# Does AVRO supports schema evolution?

Tags: avro

I am trying to understand whether AVRO supports schema evolution for the following case.

1. Kafka Producer writing using schema1
2. Then again producer writing using schema2 - A new field added with default value
3. Kafka Consumer consuming above both message using schema1?

I am able to read the first message successfully from Kafka but for the second message I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. Ie - I am reading the second message (written using schema2) using schema1. Is this expected not to work? Is it expected to update the consumer first always?

Other option is to use schema registry but I don't want to opt this. So I would like know whether schema evolution for above case is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading Avro data, you always need two schemata: the writer schema and the reader schema (they may be the same).

I'm assuming you're writing the data to Kafka using the `BinaryMessageEncoder`. This adds a 10-byte header describing the write schema.

To read the message (using the `BinaryMessageDecoder`), you'll need to give it the read schema (`schema1`) and a `SchemaStore`. This latter can be connected to a schema registry, but it need not. You can also use the `SchemaStore.Cache` implementation and add `schema2` to it.

When reading the data, the `BinaryMessageDecoder` first reads the header, resolves the writer schema, and then reads the data as `schema1` data.

Comment: In that case, reading schema2 message it not at all possible using schema1?

Comment: @Invisible You need to add fields in a way that are forward or full compatible - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#forward-compatibility

Comment: @OneCricketeer My question is for plain Avro not with schema registry

Comment: @Invisible I understand that, but the documentation there is not specific to the Registry. It only describes how evolution works.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Right!. In that case, the document that you shared says to upgrade the producer first for "forward" but in theory, I need the schemav2 for the consumer to read the message that is written by schemav2. Means I want to update the consumer first? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Invisible That page also documents what order that services should be updated based on different compatibility modes. It says consumers should be updated after producers, yes, for forward mode

Comment: @Invisible, that is correct: in order to read data you need the write schema. This means that the consumer somehow needs to know about schema2 before reading schema2 data. This can be hardcoded or via a SchemaStore (either connected to a schema registry or some custom solution).

Comment: @OscarWestravanHolthe-Kind - It makes sense now. Thanks a lot. So in the streaming world (especially in the Kafka with retention of 7 days), we can expect multiple changes in the schema (say 5 to 10 times per week during initial stage), and in ideal world, it is expected to have multiple consumers, so it looks like the default Avro model schema evolution is kind of pain as updating all the consumers before producer change is kind of difficult in real world :)

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Thanks for input. Could you please double check your statement again? You say it is "forward" mean "consumers should be updated **after** producers", but OscarWestravanHolthe-Kind statement is opposite (it is backward - "consumers should be updated **before** producers"). From my local testing, I think OscarWestravanHolthe-Kind's statement is correct. Means, the default Avro schema evolution supports "backward" not "forward". Am I right?

Comment: @Invisible Avro itself has no "default evolution"; it all depends on how you add fields... As the linked docs say - removing a field is an example of a backward change. Adding a new field is a forward change, and introducing that field with a default is a forward and backward (full) change. If you centralize the schemas in some shared repo/dependency, then the producers almost always are driving any schema change, which consumer can optionally react to. Otherwise, consumers can freely remove fields or add new fields with defaults without any interaction from producer lifecycles

Comment: Forwards or backwards only makes sense with schema version compatibility. In terms of rolling out new schemata, it's always consumer acces to write schemata first. This is because single encoded messages is a stream only contain a reference to the write schema. This is also why a dynamic approach with a `SchemaStore` connected to some global store is a good idea: you can give all consumers access to the new write schema without deploying.

Comment: Thanks @OscarWestravanHolthe-Kind. It completely makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you ask is possible (with binary encoding) i.e. update the schema in the producer without updating it in the consumer. This is because Avro puts a fingerprint into each message. Change the schema (e.g. evening adding a new nullable field), you change the fingerprint. The consumer does not know the new fingerprint and cannot decode the message.

You can do what you ask in Protobuf.

Comment: This is good explantation: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html